# Bring up the map by having the city name with OpenStreetMap API

Tags: javascript, api, openstreetmap

Can I bring up directly (knowing only the name of the city and not the coordinates) the map of city with the OpenStreetMap API like Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the nominatim service as an intermediate step to look up the coordinates of the map you want before fetching the mapdata through the openstreetmap api.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup